# React Native expo there was a prob loading this experience

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, expo

When i run 'exp start' from command line. my react native app builds perfectly on simulator and on device. i also ran exp start --no-dev which i assumed was to show what would run with dev mode flag off when i run exp publish. When i run 'exp publish' i get

`There was a problem loading this experience.`

Try Again

Error: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module(calling runApplication)
Error Code: CLIENT_LOADING_ERROR
Status Code: 2

just confused because if i run the command with dev mode turned off it still loads and runs perfectly on simulator and on device until i run exp publish and run the ipa file on my device then it breaks.

Comment: I had same issue. I deleted the expo app. Run this command `react-native run-ios` which installs expo app and starts it just fine

Comment: My app is detached. would that still work? It works if i run 'exp start' and start the app in xcode. it is after i run exp publish and create the ipa file and install it on my phone via xcode or manifest download link from my server. i get that error.